# How to merge 2 topics in ROS2?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to integrate nav2 into one of my robots and I'm almost done.
Nav2 is publishing movement information into /cmd_vel while my robot is looking for that info through /robo/cmd_vel. I can't change the requirement from /robo/cmd_vel so is there any easy way to take information published in /cmd_vel into /robo/cmd_vel?

I initially considered writing a node to simply transfer the data but this seems like a task that would have a pre-existing command for ROS2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405765/how-to-merge-2-topics-in-ros2?/) by [Thugunb](https://answers.ros.org/users/114884/thugunb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to remap the /cmd_vel topic in your launch file for nav2 to publish to the topic you want. Relevant snippet from this answer: [how-to-remap-topic-in-a-ros2-launch-file](https://answers.ros.org/question/376720/how-to-remap-topic-in-a-ros2-launch-file/)

```
forward_turtlesim_commands_to_second_turtlesim_node = Node(
    package='turtlesim',
    executable='mimic',
    name='mimic',
    remappings=[
        ('/input/pose', '/turtlesim1/turtle1/pose'),
        ('/output/cmd_vel', '/turtlesim2/turtle1/cmd_vel'),
    ]
)
```

The node to republish a topic to a different topic already exists in the [topic_tools](https://github.com/ros-tooling/topic_tools) package, the relay node there specifically, but as I said, in this case you would just want to remap the topic that nav2 outputs.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2022-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1